# Do While Loop for SKU numbers

Tags: excel, do-while, vba

I am trying to automate my SKU numbers. I have 3 columns. The first column has `28`, the second has `6` and finally the third has `58`.

I want the SKU to have a Trend like so `0{(###)col1}{(##)col2}{(##)col3}0`

My Code looks like this

```
Sub SKU()
    Dim x As Long
    x = 1
    i = 1
    j = 1
    k = 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Do While Cells(j, 2) <> ""
            Do While Cells(k, 3) <> ""
                Cells(x, 4).Value = Format(0, "0") & Format(i, "000") & _
                Format(j, "00") & Format(k, "00") & Format(0, "0")
                k = k + 1
                x = x + 1
            Loop
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: My results Is not getting past the K loop BTW

Comment: What is your question?  (Which part doesn't work as expected? )  how your data looks like?  What is your desired output?

Comment: Remove first and second `do-while` loop then replace your line with: `Cells(k, 4).Value = Format(Cells(k, 1), "0") & Format(Cells(k, 2), "000") & Format(Cells(k, 3), "00")`  and everything should be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the `Do` Loop. Find the last row and then use a `For` loop.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If .Cells(i, 1) <> "" And .Cells(i, 2) <> "" And .Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then

                '0{(###)col1}{(##)col2}{(##)col3}0
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = "'0" & _
                                     Format(.Cells(i, 1), "000") & _
                                     Format(.Cells(i, 2), "00") & _
                                     Format(.Cells(i, 3), "00") & _
                                     "0"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Output for `28,6,58` is `002806580`

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, remove first and second `do-while` loop then replace:

```
Cells(x, 4).Value = Format(0, "0") & Format(i, "000") & _
           Format(j, "00") & Format(k, "00") & Format(0, "0")
```

with:

```
Cells(k, 4) = "'" & Format(Cells(k, 1), "000") & _
           Format(Cells(k, 2), "00") & Format(Cells(k, 3), "00")
```

Result: `0280658`

In case you want to add leading and ending zeros:

```
Cells(k, 4) = "'0" & Format(Cells(k, 1), "000") & _
           Format(Cells(k, 2), "00") & Format(Cells(k, 3), "00") & "0"
```

Result: `002806580`

Comment: ++ nice one :) I think he needs the last one from your post